# jQuery Timepicker plugin not working

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I can't seem to get this basic [timepicker](http://timepicker.co/) to work on my form:

http://realendeavors.com/dmv-form/htmlform.htm

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: You need to show us your code and whats the error message?

Comment: You haven't linked jQuery yet. Your console is saying your `&` cannot be found.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/20/

Comment: Sorry - my comment above should say `$` not `&`. Can no longer edit the comment so.....

Answer (score 1):

In order to use jQuery plugins you must **include jQuery itself** first, for example in this way:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your code **before** you call the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the jQuery lib when using jQuery plugins.

```
//Always load hQuery first.
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

//Then your plugins
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

//Then your custom code
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
  });
</script>
```

Maybe you also need to change your input type from text to date or time?

```
<input class="timepicker" type="date" name="best_time" maxlength="80" size="30">
```